# How to span a 28' gap, preferably with wood

Tags: structural-engineering, wood

I am building a temporary structure in a windy area (this is for Burning Man).  We are essentially using 4x4s that are embedded into the ground (hard clay floor) that are spaced apart by 2x6 rafters.  The purpose of this structure is to hold some shade sails which will effectively catch a reasonable amount of wind (though we try to take them down if the wind gets too strong), and otherwise the structure is not load bearing.

Here's a sketch of the structure:

[image: shade structure]

The problem is that this year we want the long rafters to reach about 27'.  Previous years were 24' long, a lumber length that is reasonably easy to find.  Furthermore, we previously only had rafters across the angular spans, there were no horizontal beams for support, and the shade structure was more than able to handle the wind load (to give an idea of what forces we are dealing with).

We can't find 28' 2x6 lumber in our area (or order it in time to get here), so I am considering my options, and so far I've come up with:

1. Using I-Joists (most expensive)
2. Sistering 2x8s together and figuring out a hanger solution
3. Sistering 2x6s together and hoping for the best (least expensive).

By "sistering" I mean to sandwich two 2x6s or 2x8s together (in offset lengths) to reach the full 27' using wood glue and then heavy duty screws on both sides (or perhaps bolting them together in a number of places if we wanted easier storage).

I have a feeling that #3 is enough, considering we'd also be adding the horizontal beams on the outside rafters and collar ties (or maybe a "half collar tie?) on the inner rafters.

Any thoughts on whether this would be good enough, considering what has worked for us before?

Comment: What are your legal implications if this hits someone on the head?

Comment: In a Q&A site full of engineers, I doubt anyone's going to recommend "hoping for the best" as an acceptable strategy.

Comment: Well - forgetting legal implications, the ethical complications are more concerning.  I don't want to hit anyone on the head.  Are you thinking that the beams would actually split and fall?

Comment: Wasabi - hoping for the best is the best we've got.  :)

Comment: Perhaps a better question is this - if 2x6 rafters at 24' without any beams worked fine for us, is this going to be just as strong or stronger?